# multiple conditions on a sql Aggregate Function

Tags: mysql

How do you group by multiple conditions on a sql Aggregate Function. For instance I have two tables `Sales` and `Accounts`

`Sales`

```
ID  |  identifier_one  |  identifier_two  | quantity | date
1   |       1          |       A1         |    1     |  2017-01-01
2   |       1          |       B1         |    1     |  2017-01-01
3   |       1          |       A1         |    1     |  2017-01-02
```

The Query should populate the accounts table as so

`Accounts`

```
ID  |  identifier_one  |  identifier_two  |  current_month  |  current_year
1   |       1          |       A1         |    2            |     2
2   |       1          |       B1         |    1            |     1
```

I had this query but it only takes in account `identifier_one` so in this example both entries in accounts would have `3` and `3`

```
$sales = DB::select('SELECT
                            identifier_one,
                            SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()), quantity, 0)) AS current_year,
                            SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURDATE() ), quantity, 0)) AS current_month,
                            SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1, quantity, 0)) AS last_year,
                            SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURDATE()) - 1, quantity, 0)) AS last_month
                        FROM sales
                        GROUP BY identifier_one'); 

foreach ($sales as $sale) {

                    DB::table('accounts')
                        ->where([
                            ['identifier_one', '=', $sale->identifier_one]
                        ])
                        ->update([
                            'current_year'  => $sale->current_year,
                            'current_month' => $sale->current_month,
                            'last_month'    => $sale->last_month,
                            'last_year'     => $sale->last_year
                        ]);


                }
```

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something but just a comma and the field name int eh group by.... `GROUP BY identifier_one, identifier_two` and if you want add identifier_two to the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you just need to add a , and the field name to the group by.
You may want to add identifier_two to the select as well in case the where clause needs to be updated to account for both identifiers. (Likely)

```
SELECT identifier_one
     , identifier_two  --not required but may be useful as you seem to filter on identifier_one later; maybe you also need the 2nd one...
     , SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()), quantity, 0)) AS current_year,
     , SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURDATE() ), quantity, 0)) AS current_month
     , SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1, quantity, 0)) AS last_year
     , SUM(IF(YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURDATE()) - 1, quantity, 0)) AS last_month
FROM sales
GROUP BY identifier_one, identifier_two --this is what you're missing
```

Comment: I was going to say on update I should add to `where()` clause `['identifier_two', '=', $sale->identifier_two]`

Comment: but all in all it seems to give all 3 the same amount still

Comment: I don't see how that's possible.  The `GROUP BY identifier_one, identifier_two` will ensure the sum is calculated for each unique pairing of identifier_one and identifier_two.  in this case, you should only get 2 rows returned

Comment: I think the issue is I need both conditions to match and return on row of sales" So add all sales together when both identifier_one and identifier_one are same and then give me each "sale"

Comment: We're saying the same thing.  1,A1 and 1,B1 are the unique parings.  1,A1 would be summed to 2 and 1,B1 would be 1.  If you're getting 3 then the group by isn't being executed for some reason.

Comment: Okay, I will look at that grouping

Comment: Got it, dumb mistake. The DB was never reset after I did the first update so when I ran it again some accounts didnt match the where parameters so they stayed the same. When I reset everything again and ran it, it was good

Comment: Field Goal up it looks Gooooooood! :P